# Azure AD Connect Import

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id, identity-management

I'm running into an issue with the latest version, 4.1.1.180, that I can't resolve.

After installation, the AD Connector is now failing and throwing errors.  They fail on the import and export run profiles.

They sync fails with the `no-start-ma` status

The event log then registers two events

```
Event: 6005

The management agent "Domain.INT" failed on run profile "Export" because of an unspecified management agent error.
 Additional Information

 %3
```

Event 6401

```
 "ERR_: MMS(2276): ..\libutils.cpp(10143): Failed to start run because of undiagnosed MA error
Azure AD Sync 1.1.180.0"
```

I've installed the latest updates for .NET 4.5 and then installed .NET 4.6.1 but with same results (so it's currently running now with .NET 4.6.1).

Additionally, if you open the connector itself and try to refresh the schema or view the containers (OU"s) it throws an error

[image]

I've re-ran the configuration wizard - and this completes without error.
If I save the Import profile output it doesn't show me anything - it is connecting successfully to the-the domain controller.

```
   <ma-connection>
    <connection-log><incident><connection-result>success</connection-result><date>2016-05-13 18:04:35.121</date><server>DC.Domain.int:389</server></incident></connection-log>
   </ma-connection>
```

There are no errors logged from the profile.  I also enabled the AD Sync event logs - but nothing is getting logged there either.  As far as I can tell there are no other application logs we can check in the Azure AD directories. 
One other thing of note is that password sync continues to work - but new objects or changes to objects are not synced.

Comment: If I were you, I'd try to install the AD Connect tool on another machine, it doesn't matter where as long as it has access to the DCs and Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem happen to me, and in troubleshooting I found this MSDN forum post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8cdb6596-11ce-4b06-a02c-14ea440146bc/problems-with-latest-azure-ad-connect?forum=WindowsAzureAD

This fixed it for me without needing to do anything else:

"Just run Synchronization Service Manager (miisclient.exe), and check Properties of Active Directory Domain Services Connector which failed import or export. On left panel of “properties” dialog, click “Connect to Active Directory Forest”, check on the right panel, for the "Domain:" field, if it is NetBIOS name specified, need to change NetBIOS name to Fully Qualified Domain Name, then enter account password and click "OK" button to save the connector property. This should fix this issue."

Comment: Yeah we reverted back on this installation and I installed a new instance on a new server.  That of course worked. I didn't go back and check Forums, so thanks for pointing this out.